# Modeling a binary constraint in AMPL - CPLEX

Tags: linear-programming, cplex, ampl

i have the following constraints

[image]

i tried to model it in AMPL using the following code:

```
var y {1..njobs} binary;

subject to overlap 
    {i in 1..njobs, j in i+1..njobs: i<>j}:
        xi[i] + si[i] <= xi[j]+m*y[i];

 subject to order
    {i in 1..njobs, j in i+1..njobs: i<j}:
        y[i] + y[j] = 1;
```

i'm new to this topic and seem to miss something in the code above. any suggestions?

Comment: http://or.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the constraints, y has two indices, i and j, but your code only gives it a single index.

Should be something like:

```
var y {1..njobs,1..njobs} binary;
subject to overlap 
    {i in 1..njobs, j in i+1..njobs: i<>j}:
        xi[i] + si[i] <= xi[j]+m*y[i,j];

 subject to order
    {i in 1..njobs, j in i+1..njobs: i<j}:
        y[i,j] + y[j,i] = 1;
```

Currently the behaviour for when i = j is undefined. You may want to either add a constraint that defines the behaviour in that case, or exclude it from the index space when you declare y, e.g.:

```
var y {i in 1..njobs,j in 1..njobs: i <> j} binary;
```

Comment: Thank you! i have a follow up to the question with the full model, and didn't ant it to post it here so i can accept your answer. can i post a new question with the full model and get an answer from you there so i can accept it too?

Comment: @khedir Yes, if it's a different question, post it as a new question. (SO works on a model of one question per post.) As Rodrigo suggested, you might consider asking on the OR site.